# Cordova statusbar color plugin not working in mi Ui phones

Tags: ionic-framework, cordova-plugins, android-statusbar

I am realy new to cordova hybrid app development.
I am working with ionic app and installed plugin cordova-plugin-statusbar and set preference in the config.xml

After building installed on my **red mi note 3**. But status bar color was not working. So then i checked on motorola phone it was working.

Can anyone tell me the reason for this behavior.

And how i can troubleshoot where is the problem

[Apk file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0HqPxSLo_RGaGlyQVlEQkpoWEU/view?usp=drivesdk)

Answer (score 0):

ionic plugin rm cordova-plugin-statusbar

or

ionic plugin rm org.apache.cordova.statusbar

ionic plugin add https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-statusbar.git